# VMware View 6.0 Windows 7 Lock Screen

Tags: windows, vmware-esx

I'm running VMware View 6.0.1 with Automated Windows 7 X64 Pools. Domain/AD-Level: Windows Server 2012.

My Problem is that after about 15 Minutes inactivity Windows 7 will lock the Workstation (Press CTRL+ALT+DEL Screen). There is no GPO whatsoever that is triggering this kind of behavior. And it only happens on the VDI-Desktops. The FAT-Clients are Fine. All the Energysaving/Screensaver Settings are turned off.
Can someone tell me what is triggering the Lockscreen?
Thank you in Advance!